# How to create a File representing a path on a Windows server without mapping a drive?

Tags: java, windows, file, remote-server

I tried this:

```
URI uri = URI.create( "file://servername/e$/somefile" );
File file = new File(uri);
```

but it threw:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Windows style path (with a leading triple slash):

```
File file = new File("\\\\\\server\\e$\\somefile");
```

Comment: Why triple slashes and not double?

Answer (score 1):

Use [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/), with `smb://[[[domain;]username[:password]@]server[:port]/[[share]]`-style URLs, or one day you'll wake up, try to run your app from a different OS, and find that the concept of "write once, run anywhere" is even more hilarious than you thought it was.

Comment: As per title and tags, this question has Windows context (only). There is no chance of my code ever running on another OS.